# How to create users in CAS with "OpenLDAP"?

Tags: cas, openldap

I did what the documentation said about setting up an LDAP authentication in CAS. (https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html)

The CAS server is running so far, but could not create a user to log in with LDAP credentials. I am using JXplorer to add a user and I added this to `deployerConfigContext.xml`:

```
<ldaptive:bind-search-authenticator id="authenticator"
        ldapUrl="${ldap.url}"
        baseDn="${ldap.baseDn}"
        userFilter="${ldap.authn.searchFilter}"
        bindDn="${ldap.managerDn}"
        bindCredential="${ldap.managerPassword}"
        connectTimeout="${ldap.connectTimeout}"
        useStartTLS="${ldap.useStartTLS}"
        blockWaitTime="${ldap.pool.blockWaitTime}"
        maxPoolSize="${ldap.pool.maxSize}"
        allowMultipleDns="${ldap.allowMultipleDns:false}"
        usePasswordPolicy="${ldap.usePpolicy:false}"
        minPoolSize="${ldap.pool.minSize}"
        validateOnCheckOut="${ldap.pool.validateOnCheckout}"
        validatePeriodically="${ldap.pool.validatePeriodically}"
        validatePeriod="${ldap.pool.validatePeriod}"
        idleTime="${ldap.pool.idleTime}"
        prunePeriod="${ldap.pool.prunePeriod}"
        failFastInitialize="true"
        subtreeSearch="${ldap.subtree.search:true}"
        useSSL="${ldap.use.ssl:false}"
    />
```

And then, I added this to the `cas.properties` file:

```
#========================================
# General properties
#========================================
ldap.url=ldap://myip:389

# Start TLS for SSL connections
ldap.useStartTLS=false

# Directory root DN
# ldap.rootDn=dc=com

# Base DN of users to be authenticated
ldap.baseDn=ou=people,dc=maxcrc,dc=com

# LDAP connection timeout in milliseconds
ldap.connectTimeout=3000

# Manager credential DN
ldap.managerDn=cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com

# Manager credential password
ldap.managerPassword=secret
#========================================
# LDAP connection pool configuration
#========================================
ldap.pool.minSize=1
ldap.pool.maxSize=10
ldap.pool.validateOnCheckout=false
ldap.pool.validatePeriodically=true

# Amount of time in milliseconds to block on pool exhausted condition
# before giving up.
ldap.pool.blockWaitTime=3000

# Frequency of connection validation in seconds
# Only applies if validatePeriodically=true
ldap.pool.validatePeriod=300

# Attempt to prune connections every N seconds
ldap.pool.prunePeriod=300

# Maximum amount of time an idle connection is allowed to be in
# pool before it is liable to be removed/destroyed
ldap.pool.idleTime=600

#========================================
# Authentication
#========================================
ldap.authn.searchFilter=cn={user}

# Ldap domain used to resolve dn
ldap.domain=example.org

# Should LDAP Password Policy be enabled?
ldap.usePpolicy=false

# Allow multiple DNs during authentication?
ldap.allowMultipleDns=false
```

Now, I could not find any information on how to create a user in LDAP for CAS. Yes, I saw some attributes that seem to be legit. So I created an `organizationalPerson` in JXplorer. I set a password and try to log in with the user name (`cn=...`). But as I expected, that did not work.

Is there any information out there what CAS is actually expecting to get from LDAP? There must be some kind of guideline. The `cas.properties` information says: *Base DN of users to be authenticated*, but how does CAS know what attribute the user has, or does he even has to know it?

So to sum my question up: How do I create a user in LDAP, OR how does the user has to look like? What do I have to do with CAS (`deployerConfigContext.xml`) that CAS understands my LDAP-Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAS does not care about your ldap schema, as long as your describe it correctly in your configuration. CAS is also not an LDAP server, and will never populate a LDAP server and/or create a schema.